# subtracting data from a quarter to previous quarter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My dataset contains information about the amount in the corresponding quarter.(year 2016-2020 actually)

I require a change in the amount previous quarter.[Column G]

**Method used by me** :
I tried to add  'pervious quarter' field to it and subtract it by matching the 'original quarter' from the 'previous quarter'

Table 1 - original data

Table 2 - original data + date_sub(QUARTER  ,interval 1 Quarter )as previous_quarter

```
with a as (SELECT * FROM `table1` ),
b as (SELECT * FROM `table2` )

SELECT * ,(a.amount - b.amount)
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b 
on a.Name = b.Name  and
a.ID=b.ID and
a.QUARTER=b.previous_quarter
```

**Issue** - somehow this method isn't giving me proper delta

Comment: Have you tried with LAG: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag  ?

Comment: Something like `..., amount - LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY quarter) FROM table1`

Comment: Hi @mp.kaur, is the attached image the unexpected result you got when run the query or what you expected to get from the query ?

Comment: image shows the expected result (green column G).

Comment: Lag function worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

It appears @Lennart's suggestion to use LAG navigation function works for this inquiry.

> Have you tried with LAG: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag

> Lag function worked pretty well.

Marking this as an answer (Community Wiki)